# Как восстановить grub

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, восстановление, uefi

Восстанавливаю grub на EFI разделе ubuntu 18.04 64 bit на виртуалке внутри Hyper-V на Windows 10

Посоветовали, что возможно проблема связана с запорченым grub

```
sudo fdisk -l  /dev/sda

/dev/sda1 EFI System
/dev/sda2 Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3 Linux swap


sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
```

После этой команды ошибка

```
chroot: failed to run command '/bin/bash': Exec format error

ldd /bin/bash
```

выдает список зависимых библиотек

В инете встречается много инструкций, но chroot в каждой заканчивается этой ошибкой, в от способа решения не нашел.

Comment: Интересный у вас способ монтирования специальных файловых систем.

Comment: А что не так? И как правильно?